# Can I use Apache Camel in an AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, apache-camel

Apache Camel has a number of features which make event processing elegant and easy to code. It would be useful to be able to exploit this in an AWS Lambda.

Of course not all features are appropriate, especially anything requiring a long lived process.

Also managing persistant state, for example idempotent repositories and throttling would need thinkng about.

But it would be really useful in simple cases.

Comment: I tried to follow the sample code got blocked by Null Pointer Exception because the CamelContext is not getting injected at runtime when the Lamdba function gets invoked. I have raised an issue in the git repo with details https://github.com/jcable/SampleCamelLambda/issues/1

Comment: Just spotted this @ravishankar - I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is simple using Redhat's Quarkus framework.

I've made a simple example: https://github.com/jcable/SampleCamelLambda

The Camel Route is trivial:

```
from("direct:input").to("log:input")
    .process(new Processor() {
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            InputObject input = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputObject.class);
            String result = input.getGreeting() + " " + input.getName();
            OutputObject out = new OutputObject();
            out.setResult(result);
            out.setRequestId("aws-request-1");
            exchange.getIn().setBody(out);
          }
    });
```

Adapting the route to the Lambda makes use of a Quarkus RequestHandler.

```
public class Lambda implements RequestHandler<InputObject, OutputObject> {

    @Inject
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Override
    public OutputObject handleRequest(InputObject input, Context context) {
        return camelContext.createProducerTemplate().requestBody("direct:input", input, OutputObject.class);
    }
}
```

CDI is used to inject the CamelContext into the request handler and then the camelContext object is used to create a
ProducerTemplate which can be used to invoke the Camel route.

The Maven project for the example is derived from the Quarkus lambda example with Apache Camel dependencies from the Camel Quarkus examples.